# How can you do an update to a table in another database using postgres dblink?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink, postgres-fdw

The query that has to be executed is as simple as below -

```
Update employee set is_done=true;
```

The table that I want to update is only present in another database.

I have been using these kinds of dblink queries.

```
INSERT Into mytable select * from 
dblink('host=10.1.1.1
 user=user
 password=password
 dbname=oat', 'SELECT * from employee') tt(
     user_id integer,
     is_done boolean

 ) on conflict(user_id) do nothing;
```

How can I update a field of employee table, which is on another database?

I also want to know if we can achieve doing a delete as well in a similar manner - delete an entire row for a given id

Also, what if I had to do a join with the current database table in the update query?

Comment: A foreign data wrapper would be a better solution

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Could you please provide an example, thanks

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-exec.html at the bottom examples

Comment: This worked for me. 

   

     select * from dblink('host=10.1.1.1
         user=user
         password=password
         dbname=oat','Update employee set is_done =true' ) tt(
         updated text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
 select * from dblink('host=10.1.1.1
     user=user
     password=password
     dbname=oat','Update employee set is_done =true' ) tt(
     updated text);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT dblink_connect('host=10.1.1.1
 user=user
 password=password
 dbname=oat');

SELECT dblink_exec('Update employee set is_done=true');
```

And I recommend you using FDW as well, especially if you are on 9.6

**update**

for dblink you "wrap" qry and send it. so the only way to "join" wrapped query is dynamic SQL in `DO` block. Which would be very ugly. Concider creating `FOREIGN TABLE` - it will allow you to update from local table easily

**update two**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createserver.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createusermapping.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html

so you create server, map user and create a foreign table.

after completing update it as if it was local

Comment: Thanks. I guess this would work as well. Can you also edit your answer for the last question in my description about making a join

Comment: well, 9.6 would allow you to do remote joins. and regarding you last question - do you mean you want to update with CTE join?..

Comment: I don't know what a CTE join is. Its a simple join between user_id in the remote employee table and id of a local table

Comment: you definitely could do that with foreign table. and dblink... so far I see only dynamic sql in `DO` block...

Comment: I thought about CTE, because you mentionned join in update.https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html but  you probably meant `update .. from dblink_table ... join local_table`

Comment: I can use some help on how to go about using foreign table. Do you mind updating your answer please? Basically, I want to update a table in remote database by doing a join with my local database table

Comment: it does not. It's like a wrapper that allows one db to see other db's table like own - I'm very much simplifying it, but in short - it exposes other db table to look like local

Comment: Oh but the problem is that I have to update a table in remote db. If I create a foriegn table for this remote db table, can I update the foreign table?

Comment: yes. I meant that foreign table does not need any "refresh" to be actual, it is not like Oracle materialized view or smth. but of course you can update rows in it. (if user permissions allow that)

Comment: I tried running an update command on the foriegn table I created. I get this ERROR - relation "db.foriegntable" does not exist

Comment: lets not spam here? :) put commands you used to create it and your error in new question?

Comment: My question is posted here with details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675766/what-am-i-doing-here-while-updating-a-table-in-a-remote-db-using-postgres-fdw